# using flexbox to vertical align text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

flexbox should make things a lot simpler it seems, but I can't seem to get the text links and images in this menu to align vertically. The text links and images are centered vertically and horizontally instead. What's missing? I'm probably also over doing it as if I were using tables and vertical-align. I want everything to align to the bottom.

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header > div {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

header > div > a {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    float: left;
    align-self: flex-end;
    height: 279px;
    line-height: 279px;
}

header > div > ul {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    float: left;
    align-self: flex-end; 
    height: 279px;
    line-height: 279px;
}

header .menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 279px;
    line-height: 279px;
}

header .menu li a {
    display: block;
    align-self: flex-end;
height: 279px;
line-height: 279px;
}

    <header>
        <div>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://eu2013.ie/media/eupresidency/content/imagegalleryitems/twitter-bird-blue-on-white-small.png" />
            </a>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                <li style="background: url('http://printready.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/facebook-like-icon-300x279.png') no-repeat; width: 300px; height: 279px;"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rpbwdvxe/1/

Comment: Where do you want to align it?

Comment: just updated the question, I want the image, the text links and the last li that has a background image to align to the bottom. everything seems to be centered aligned horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set flex on `header > div`'s children, and `align-self` on its grandchildren:

```
header > div {
  display: flex;
}

header > div > * {
  display: flex;
}

header > div > * > * {
  align-self: flex-end;    
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pog493st/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 

header > div > a {
border: solid 1px #000;
float: left;
height: 110px;
line-height: 110px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: that'd probably work but I want to use flexbox to do all this

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.